# Investigating limit of theta like series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, theta-functions

Let $v>0$. I want to prove
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{a \in \mathbb Z} \sum_{b=1}^\infty \exp \left(-v(a/t+bt)^2\right) = 0.$$
It looks quite similar to the theta function
$$\theta(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z }e^{\pi i n^2 z}$$
which is defined on the upper half plane and obeys the transformation law
$$\theta\left(- \frac{1}{z}\right) = \sqrt{ \frac{z}{i} } \theta(z).$$
Maybe my original series can somehow be decomposed into a product of two such theta series and then we can use
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \theta(it)=1$$
and $|\theta(it)-1| < C e^{-\pi t}$.

Comment: since everything is positive, it looks like replacing sums with integrals should be a pretty good idea

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any $c > 0$ and $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\{a_0\} = a_0 - \lfloor a_0 \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of $a_0$, then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c (a - a_0)^2}
&= \sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c (a - \{a_0\})^2}
= \left(\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c (a - \{a_0\})^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c (a + \{a_0\})^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&\stackrel{\text{(C–S)}}{\geq} \sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c(a^2 + \{a_0\}^2)}
\geq \sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c(a^2+1)}.
\end{align*}

Note that this lower bound does not depend on $a_0$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{b=1}^{\infty} e^{-v(a/t + bt)^2}
= \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-(v/t^2)(a + bt^2)^2}
\geq \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} e^{-(v/t^2)(a^2+1)}
= \infty.
\end{align*}

and the limit as $t\to\infty$ also diverges to $\infty$.